# plt.scatter(X[:50,0], X[:50, 1], color = 'red', marker = 'o', label = 'setosa')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning

I have a noobie question here regarding the plt.scatter.

I am working on some machine learning tutorial where we are analyzing the petal length of two flowers.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header = None)
print(df.tail())

y = df.iloc[0:100,4].values                         #This is going to print out the 5th column of the dataset.


y = np.where(y == 'Iris-setosa', -1, 1)             #Where y has 'Iris-setosa' in there, it is going to yield a -1. Else it is going to yield a 1.


X = df.iloc[0:100, [0,2]].values                    #1st and 3rd column of the Iris dataset online
                                           #printout the 1st and 3rd

plt.scatter(X[:50,0],     X[:50, 1],    color = 'red',  marker = 'o', label = 'setosa')


plt.scatter(X[50:100, 0], X[50:100, 1], color = 'blue', marker = 'x', label = 'versicolor')
```

I don't quite get why for each of the plt.scatter lines, there are two X[:50,0] and X[:50, 1]. What is the purpose of that?? I thought that plt.scatter is meant to show one type of item when doing a scatter plot. Like I thought that it would go something like. You know that from rows 0 to 50, you want to plt scatter a certain flower so its just X[:50,0] and so on...

Thanks in advance for any input on this..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMOHs.png)

Comment: Hi. I think that depends on the data. You should know the data first.  Scatter plots may be used to visualize a *relationship* between two variables. In this case, the two measurements are values in 1st and 2nd column of `X`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes a bit. I guess what I am confused is why is it that like X[:50,0], X[50,1], color = 'red'.... there. how does plt scatter know which one to color red from that line of code.

Comment: Have you run the code? Whats the result?

Comment: The result is fine. The graph comes out great haha. 

I am just wondering why the code would not work if  say for example you took out the X[:50, 1] from the first plt.scatter code. I guess I am not understanding here what the plt.scatter is going on here.

Comment: There is one set of data plotted. Therefore red applies to the one data set.

Comment: Scatter plot in 2D, needs two measurements. Thats why `plt.scatter` needs two vector/data inputs. The `color='red'` is to color the points red. This may be useful : https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Scatterplot&ved=0ahUKEwidgrv0t7XYAhUFNI8KHWr0BgcQFggkMAA&usg=AOvVaw2QUuEZsDsDOir7wP4RUDNU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored in a 2 X 50 array. So X[50,0] maybe be width of 50 leafs while X[1,50] could be the length of the same 50 leafs. Hence you could be plotting width vs. length, for example. That combination comprises one plot set. The data will be denoted by red circles.

Comment: Oh...I see now.... Well that was dumb of me. The :50,0, and :50,1 . the 0 and 1 were referring to the column of the data source. I see it now. Thanks. Now it clicks!

Thanks Jmh!

Comment: Not dumb.  I had to think about it when I was learning python.